# In 2 John 1:9-10 is it "the teaching about Jesus" or "the teaching by Jesus"?

Tags: greek, grammar, 2-john

> CSB 2 John 1:
>
> 9 Anyone who does not remain in **Christ’s teaching** but goes beyond
> it does not have God. The one who remains in that teaching, this one
> has both the Father and the Son.
>
> 10 If anyone comes to you and does not bring **this teaching**, do not
> receive him into your home, and don’t greet him;
>
> [2Jo 1:9-10 MGNT] 9 πας ο προαγων και μη μενων εν τη διδαχη του χριστου θεον ουκ εχει ο μενων εν τη διδαχη ουτος και τον πατερα και τον υιον εχει 10 ει τις ερχεται προς υμας και ταυτην την διδαχην ου φερει μη λαμβανετε αυτον εις οικιαν και χαιρειν αυτω μη λεγετε

Comment: Sorry about my answer that was in the weeds.  I deleted it.

Comment: I apologize if the question was unclear.

Comment: Could it be both?

Comment: I'm not a guru but I think not. Not linguistically.

Comment: I reached out to the gurus and they said that no, because that would mean that the subject is both the subject and the object which is simply not the way Koine works (or any language I should think). Here's the discussion:  https://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=4615

Comment: You haven't heard about quantum physics? Where a photon can be a wave and a particle at the same time?

Comment: I hope you are joking!

Comment: I suppose it was a little bit toungue in cheek. Although I believe that both are important. Which of the two the verse you quoted cover I don't know.

Comment: The totality of Christ's teaching; it is a genitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the latter ("the teachings that Jesus taught") rather than the former ("the teachings about Jesus") was intended.  I think that if it were the former, the preposition περί would have been used, as in (with RSV translation):

> Acts 28:31
>
> *And he lived there two whole years at his own expense, and welcomed all who came to him, preaching the kingdom of God and **teaching about the Lord Jesus Christ** quite openly and unhindered.*
>
> Ἔμεινε δὲ ὁ Παῦλος διετίαν ὅλην ἐν ἰδίῳ μισθώματι καὶ ἀπεδέχετο πάντας τοὺς εἰσπορευομένους πρὸς αὐτόν, κηρύσσων τὴν βασιλείαν τοῦ Θεοῦ καὶ **διδάσκων τὰ περὶ τοῦ Κυρίου Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ** μετὰ πάσης παρρησίας ἀκωλύτως.

---

> 1 John 2:27
>
> *But the anointing which you received from him abides in you, and you have no need that any one should teach you; as his anointing **teaches you about everything**, and is true, and is no lie, just as it has taught you, abide in him.*
>
> καὶ ὑμεῖς, τὸ χρῖσμα ὃ ἐλάβετε ἀπʼ αὐτοῦ, ἐν ὑμῖν μένει, καὶ οὐ χρείαν ἔχετε ἵνα τις διδάσκῃ ὑμᾶς, ἀλλʼ ὡς τὸ αὐτὸ χρῖσμα **διδάσκει ὑμᾶς περὶ πάντων**, καὶ ἀληθές ἐστι καὶ οὐκ ἔστι ψεῦδος, καὶ καθὼς ἐδίδαξεν ὑμᾶς μενεῖτε ἐν αὐτῷ.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Then my answer is completely bogus.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I restarted from scratch

Answer (score 0):

The genitive case in Greek (as in English and many other languages) can mean any of the following:

- Belonging to someone, eg, This is the hand of David
- About or concerning someone, eg, This is the story of Moses
- Created by someone, eg, The cathedral of Gaudi
- Exclusive use (but not owned by) someone, eg, The chauffer-driven limousine of the president; or, the Palace of the Queen Elizabeth
- Conveyed by a messenger, eg, the message of the messenger about the king
- etc.

An identical construction occurs frequently in the NT and one of the most discussed is Rev 1:1, "The revelation of Jesus" which is arguably a combination of (at least) the first three above.

In the case of 2 John 9, "the teaching of Jesus", we do not necessarily need (grammatically) to exclusively decide between these possibilities because, as illustrated above, it can, at times, legitimately mean more than one of the above.  That is, in this case, we might have any of the following:

1. The teaching of Jesus could be all the doctrines about Jesus' birth, death and resurrection and saving grace, etc; that is, the teaching ABOUT Jesus.  Such teaching has been done by the apostles (2 Tim 1:13, 1 Tim 6:3)), and the Holy Spirit (John 16:13, 14).
2. The teaching of Jesus could be that which was verbally taught by Jesus, eg, Matt 4:23, 7:28, 9:35, John 7:28, 18:19, etc.  See also 1 John 2:27.  That is, the teaching BY Jesus.
3. The teaching of Jesus could also mean the teaching that Jesus conveyed about the God the Father (John 7:16).  That is (also) the teaching BY Jesus.

It appears to me that 2 John 9 is making a distinction between he legitimate "teaching of Jesus" and that which is either extrapolated ("goes beyond") from it or is false teaching about Jesus.  Such a statement is tantamount to what is "canonical" and would presumably include what we have recorded in the four canonical Gospels plus the material recorded for us by the apostles.  Nothing else.

The NT contains several other such "canonical" claims such as the true Gospel (Gal 1:8) and revelation (Rev 22:18).

Therefore, I understand 2 John 9 to mean a combination of (1), (2), & (3) above and specifically restricted to these; that is, excluding anything that disagrees with these or extrapolates from them.

Comment: I don't think that a genitive can be both subjective and objective but since I'm not a guru I reached out to b-greek with the question and am awaiting a reply:  https://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=4615

Comment: I got a response back and indeed it must be one or the other. -1

Comment: Might you share you results?  I would beg to differ.

Comment: Just follow the same link.

Comment: So would Trinity be part of the teachings of Jesus or "going beyond" and "extrapolating"?

Comment: I will ignore the distraction about the trinity.  I followed the link and cannot see how you arrived at your conclusion.  It is NOT a choice between subjective and objective at all.  But that is a matter for you.  We are only discussing shades of meaning about the genitive case.  Indeed, in most Indo-European languages (including Koine Greek) , the ablative case was absorbed into the genitive and gives it a very wide range of meanings.

Comment: The subjective and objective genitives have different subjects so it has to be one or the other. If you take exception to that then I can't help you because I'm not a guru, just passing on the message.

Comment: Forget it.  We are not discussing subject and object here.  Let us move on.

Comment: You should also see  http://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1331&p=6685&hilit=deal+of+nonsense  where the distinction you try to make is far from black and white (and from the same "authority")

Comment: What in that forum thread leads you to believe that there is any question as to whether or not a genitive must be subjective or objective or it can be both (or possessive)? I think you misread it. Where do you find the idea of a double-duty genitive in a grammar?

Comment: By the way, are you really a doctor? Of what?